# UpdateAll method related table issue .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tableadapter

I am trying to use the method `updateAll` from the table adapter manager. When I try to update any record that is stored in another table as a child the `updateAll` throws an exception telling me that "Cannot be deleted or changed because table "competition" includes related records".
Isn't this method supposed to take care of all the table relations?

Here is the code where I am saving:

```
Public Sub saveAll(ByVal dataSet As SudokuDataSet)
  Try
    Dim tbAdapterManager As New SudokuDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager

    tbAdapterManager.CompetitorTableAdapter = competitorTableAdapter
    tbAdapterManager.PuzzleTableAdapter = puzzleTableAdapter
    tbAdapterManager.CompetitionTableAdapter = competitionTableAdapter

    tbAdapterManager.UpdateAll(dataSet)
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Saving Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> The record cannot be deleted or changed because table  includes
>   related records. (Error 3200)
>
> You tried to perform an operation that
>   would have violated referential integrity rules for related tables.
>   For example, this error occurs if you try to delete or change a record
>   in the "one" table in a one-to-many relationship when there are
>   related records in the "many" table.
>
> If you want to delete or change the record, first delete the related
>   records from the "many" table.

from [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/HV080761327.aspx).

Comment: @Camus: `UpdateAll` takes care of the database layer. If you somehow managed to feed invalid data, it is your responsibility to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the method was working fine. The problem was in the database where I have to configure the relationship between the tables and set those to cascade.

i.e. Enable "Cascade Update Related Fields" and "Cascade Delete Related Fields" in the Relationship